Uniform boundedness in $W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ plus uniform boundedness of first moment imply strongly convergence subsequence
My question stems from the proof of Theorem 3.1 in this paper, which somehow suggests the following statement: Assume that the sequence of non-negative functions $\{u_k\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$ are uniformly bounded in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N) \cap W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, and if in addition the sequence $\{|x|\,u_k\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$ is uniformly bounded in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, then there exists some $u_* \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $u_k \to u_*$ strongly in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ as $k \to \infty$ (after passing to a subsequence). It appears to me that the resulting strong convergence in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ does not follow from a usual Sobolev embedding type result, and I really appreciate if someone can detail the argument/reasoning for the aforementioned statement. Thank you!

This is easy to see if you have the "right" characterization of compactness in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. In this case we have $(u_k)_k$ bounded sequence in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ has a convergent subsequence in $L^1$ if and only if both

$\| u_k(\cdot-h)-u_k\|_1 \to 0$ as $|h|\to 0$, uniformly in $k$, and
For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus K} |u_k|\, dx <\varepsilon$ for all $k$.

You can find this in Brezis' book on Functional Analysis.
Since we have
$$
\| v(\cdot -h)-v\|_1\leq |h|\| \nabla v\|_1
$$
for any $v\in W^{1,1}$, the first part of our criterion is satisfied. Then for 2, notice that if $M$ is an upper bound for $\| |x|u_k\|_1$, then for any set $K$
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus K} u_k\, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus K} |x| u_k \cdot \dfrac{1}{|x|}\, dx \leq M\cdot \sup_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus K} \dfrac{1}{|x|}.
$$
Therefore 2 is also satisfied.

Thank you very much. I have heard of Brezis's book but I never had a chance to read/study that particular book in detail. By the way, the second condition is known as "tightness of measures" if ${u_k}$ is a sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^N$ right?

@FeiCao: I believe so, yes.
